# How to set the width and height of a table to the layout size in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am trying to display the table so that all of its rows and columns are within the layout. It doesn't matter if the width or height of each cell is too small to type into.

Here is a snippet of code that shows the layout that I put the table in and the function that displays the table.

**Code generates the image shown below**: https://pastebin.com/29PjXAds

```
def createMainBody(self, MainWindow):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(layout, 0, 0)

        layout_mid = QVBoxLayout() # Layout the table is put into
        self.binInfoTable = QTableWidget()
        layout_mid.addWidget(self.binInfoTable)

        layout.addLayout(layout_mid)

        self.displayGraph(arr, color)

def displayGraph(self, graph_array, color_array):
        a = np.array(graph_array) 

        # id, R, G, B
        ca = np.array(color_array)

        * TABLE CSS *

        # Properities of the table
        self.binInfoTable.showGrid()
        self.binInfoTable.setRowCount(len(a))
        self.binInfoTable.setColumnCount(len(a[0]))
        self.binInfoTable.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.binInfoTable.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.binInfoTable.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.binInfoTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.binInfoTable.resizeColumnsToContents()

        * CODE TO FILL THE CELLS WITH COLOR *
```

**What I have**:

[image]

**What I want**:

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a QTableWidget? That's not a very good use for that kind of widget, and you might prefer a QGraphicsView instead, which would be much more flexible and responsive.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for the advice. I am trying to figure out how to use QGraphicView but it's a little confusing.

Comment: @musicamante I was able to recreate this "heatmap" on QGraphicsView but I came across an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877376/pyqt-how-to-stretch-the-width-and-height-of-a-qgraphicsview-and-qgraphicsscene. Do you think you can help me?