# PyQt5: How to make a grid using QGraphicsScene?

Tags: python, pyqt5

#### Question Description:

I am trying to create a grid like the one shown in the image below. I want to do this by using the QGraphicsScene class in PyQt5. When I run the code that I have provided down below, a window opens but the grid is no where in sight. Can someone help me figure out how I can get the grid to appear?

#### Minimal Reproducible code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QRect, QSize, Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView

class Map(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)
        self.columns = 10
        self.rows = 10

    def setColumnSize(self, columnSize):
        self.columns = columnSize

    def setRowsSize(self, rowSize):
        self.rows = rowSize

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # compute the square size based on the aspect ratio, assuming that the
        # column and row numbers are fixed
        reference = self.width() * self.rows / self.columns
        if reference > self.height():
            # the window is larger than the aspect ratio
            # use the height as a reference (minus 1 pixel)
            self.squareSize = (self.height() - 1) / self.rows
        else:
            # the opposite
            self.squareSize = (self.width() - 1) / self.columns

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qg = QGraphicsScene(self)
        width = self.squareSize * self.columns
        height = self.squareSize * self.rows
        # center the grid
        left = (self.width() - width) / 2
        top = (self.height() - height) / 2
        y = top
        # we need to add 1 to draw the topmost right/bottom lines too
        for row in range(self.rows + 1):
            qg.addLine(left, y, left + width, y)
            y += self.squareSize
        x = left
        for column in range(self.columns + 1):
            qg.addLine(x, top, x, top + height)
            x += self.squareSize

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Map()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: A QGraphicsScene requires a QGraphicsView to be displayed, and you certainly do *not* need one especially if you're going to paint in the paintEvent. Is there a specific reason for that (wrong) choice?

Comment: I had previously used QPainter in the paintEvent function so I thought I could change the code to use QGraphicsScene instead.

Comment: They are completely different objects. QPainter uses a paint device (normally, a QWidget) to paint its contents on the output device (the "screen"), while a QGraphicsScene is a more abstract object that keeps persistent objects (QGraphicsItems instances, lines, rectangles, etc) which *will* be painted afterwards if required on a QGraphicsView. I recommend you to carefully read the documentation on QGraphics frameworks.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for helping me understand the difference. I am trying to create a colormap like this: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877376/pyqt5-how-to-make-a-clickable-color-map-using-qpainter) but each square having a unique hover feature (like Qtooltip) but I have been unsuccessful. Do you know of other Qt classes that I should look into that might help me create this?